# What’s wrong with the plant in this photo?

Tags: diagnosis

I have an unknown ground covering plant in a garden bed in the San Francisco Bay Area that is a mixture of green and parts that look dead and decaying. See photo. It’s had a lot of rain over the last few months (since I moved in) so I’m guessing the problem isn’t water. Perhaps a legacy of getting too dry over Summer? Anything I can do?

[image: ground cover]

Comment: What part of the world is this?

Comment: San Francisco Bay Area

Comment: It might actually be water  I don't recognize the plant and am not really qualified to comment, but I had a number of hedges and some died just like what I am seeing there - almost certainly as a result of being exposed to to much water for to long.  (

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to the [fairy ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring) phenomenon related to fungi. The idea is that when a small plant is freshly planted in soil it establishes itself well, sets down roots and starts to propagate sideways. As it does so the roots in the centre become thick and matted and nutrients are depleted. All continues well for the new growth at the sides as it spreads into more fresh soil.

A test would be to try to dig out some of the roots in the centre. If you run into resistance from matted roots then there is your answer.

The solution is generally to rip out the dead zone, refresh the soil there and plant a new piece taken from the healthy outside growth. Then get ready to do the same surgery in a few years time.